# How to stop bots from attacking me in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How do I stop bots from attacking?

I accidentally typed in `nav_generate` so I don't know if this affected anything but if yes, how do I reverse it?

Comment: Why do you have bots if you don't want them to participate? You'll need to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Toomai There's plenty of reason to want non-attacking bots for experimentation or target practice.

Comment: Knowing exactly what the reason is will help determine what answer to give.

Answer (score 4):

By default, [Puppet Bots](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots#Puppet_bot_commands) will remain motionless, but will attack if they can see you.

```
bot -team <teamname/number> -class <classname> -name <botname>
```

You can input other commands to force these bots to take certain actions. In particular, you can use

```
bot_forceattack 0
bot_forceattack2 0
```

to prevent the bot from attacking and

```
bot_dontmove 1
```

to prevent the bot from moving.

Comment: but the bots I spawn with tf_bot_add always attack me,is there a command to stop them from attacking me?

Comment: @user93872 I've updated the answer to include an option to prevent attacking.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enable cheats with `sv_cheats 1`, but if you type `nb_blind 1` this freezes the bots and they won't shoot or move.